# Linq to Xml and creating elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have a string array:

```
string[] authors = new string[3];
authors[0] = "Charles Dickens";
authors[1] = "Robert Jordan";
authors[2] = "Robert Ludlum";
```

I am using Linq to XML to read and write XML to a given XML file, but I cannot figure out how to use the XElement class to create XML that represents my authors array.

I know it's something along the lines of

```
XElement xEle = new XElement("Authors",
from a in authors
select new XElement("Authors", ???????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
XElement xEle = new XElement("Authors",
        from a in authors
        select new XElement("Author", a));
```

That will create an `XElement` with the following XML content:

```
<Authors>
  <Author>Charles Dickens</Author>
  <Author>Robert Jordan</Author>
  <Author>Robert Ludlum</Author>
</Authors>
```

Comment: Thanks. The array was actually nested deeper in another class that I'm writing to XML, so the problem was bigger than it appears, but this got me there. I kind of a had one of those smack head moments when it clicked.